# get access to Adapter and Configuration for IBot

Tags: botframework, chatbot

I am using  [Twitter Adapter Sample](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/samples/Twitter%20Adapter%20Sample).
In class   TwitterAdapterSampleBot:IBot
I want to get access to IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter adapter,  IConfiguration configuration and ILogger logger, which are created in Startup->ConfigureServices method

I tried simple implement constructor :

```
public class TwitterAdapterSampleBot : IBot
    {
    public TwitterAdapterSampleBot(IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter adapter, IConfiguration configuration)
```

But got internal exception on startup:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core.IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter' while attempting to activate 'TwitterAdapter_Sample.TwitterAdapterSampleBot'.
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChai

Answer (score 0):

This *"IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter"* interface using to express the relationship between an mvc api Controller and a Bot Builder Adapter. So you need to resolve the dependency issue with it's implementation.

IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter is implemented in "BotFrameworkHttpAdapter" ( Bot Builder Adapter implementation ) class.

**ConfigureServices in Asp.Net Core Startup Class:**

```
services.AddSingleton<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter, BotFrameworkHttpAdapter>();
```

You can implement the above scenario in another way for example create a botframework custom adapter error handler class with the implementation of BotFrameworkHttpAdapter.

**Microsoft docs example:**

```
public class AdapterWithErrorHandler : BotFrameworkHttpAdapter
{
    private static log4net.ILog logger
        = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public AdapterWithErrorHandler(
        ICredentialProvider credentialProvider,
        ConversationState conversationState = null)
        : base(credentialProvider)
    {
        OnTurnError = async (turnContext, exception) =>
        {
            // Log any leaked exception from the application.
            logger.Error($"Exception caught : {exception.Message}");

            // Send a catch-all apology to the user.
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("Sorry, it looks like something went wrong.");

            if (conversationState != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Delete the conversationState for the current conversation to prevent the
                    // bot from getting stuck in a error-loop caused by being in a bad state.
                    // ConversationState should be thought of as similar to "cookie-state" in a Web pages.
                    await conversationState.DeleteAsync(turnContext);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    logger.Error($"Exception caught on attempting to Delete ConversationState : {e.Message}");
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**ConfigureServices in Asp.Net Core Startup Class:**

```
// Create the Bot Framework Adapter with error handling enabled. 
services.AddSingleton<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter, AdapterWithErrorHandler>();
```

**Reference:**

1. [Microsoft V4 docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/migration/conversion-core?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)
2. [BotFrameworkHttpAdapter docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.integration.aspnet.core.botframeworkhttpadapter?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable)